# Multiple paths for same route function in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I've built a service using Node, Express & Mongoose. At the moment it renders templates to the front-end but I want to extend the functionality to a full API.

I'd like to use a single route for each type of resource to be returned with a flag to tell the server to return API content or to render the view and respond with the HTML.

Examples of this would be as follows:

- `/users/:userId`
- `/api/users/:userId`

Both would use the same function (i.e. `users.getOne`) which would then check if the path `api` is present and send the correct response accordingly.

I could obviously just do the following:

```
app.get( '/users/:userId', users.getOne );
app.get( '/api/users/:userId', users.getOne );
```

and check in the response handler, though I'd rather not have 2 routes defined for each resource.

Comment: you could make a simple dispatch function that added both; one with "/api" prepended on the route, then call it like addGet("/users/:userId", users.getOne); it could event do other fancy stuff, or accept a flag to disable one path or the other; it can help your over-all program cleanliness rather than detract from it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use Path Patterns or Regular Expressions in your route paths.

Using path patterns your route would look like this:

```
app.get( '(/api)?/users/:userId', users.getOne );
```